# iPhone - UIScrollView with Interface Builder

Tags: interface-builder, uiscrollview

i have to set some objects like UILabel and UIImageView in my scroll view from Interface Builder. But, how can i do?? I know that this can be done from code, but for a multilanguage app is too annoying :)

EDIT:
I solve the problem!
I explain again and better the problem : i had to "draw" my view with UIScrollView with Interface Builder because is the easiest way to manage multilanguage view. First, we have to add UIScrollView in our view. But in this case we don't be able to insert objects in a point that have height > 460. So, i've added a scroll view, but not in my view and i've modified its height and i now add objects everywhere i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! I explain again and better the problem : i had to "draw" my view with UIScrollView with Interface Builder because is the easiest way to manage multilanguage view. First, we have to add UIScrollView in our view. But in this case we don't be able to insert objects in a point that have height > 460. So, i've added a scroll view, but not in my view and i've modified its height and i now add objects everywhere i want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific. What problems did you encounter? Generally all you need to do is to drag&drop your outlets in the scroll view (and optionally bind them to IBOutlet fields you may have in your controller class, according to what you need to do).